# Jquery UI Sortable Set Order

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to create list items, which I saved sorted list to database.

I have gave them id when i click save button I save their index to their id.

**How can I set same order as i did.**

```js
$("#get-index-button").on("click", function(){
  console.log($("#item1").index()+1);
  console.log($("#item2").index()+1);
  console.log($("#item3").index()+1);
  console.log($("#item4").index()+1);
  console.log($("#item5").index()+1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item1"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item2"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item3"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item4"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default" id="item5"></span>Item 5</li>
</ul>

<button id="get-index-button">Save</button>
```

If I save this list as down below how can I set as this order after save to DB.

```
2
3
5
1
4
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept and give upvote it to help other programmers for finding a solution when they have same issue. The majority of programmers see accepted or upvoted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

```
// customOrder is your order that you saved in db 
var custumOrder = ["item4", "item2", "item1", "item3"];

var ul = $("#sortable");
var items = $("#sortable li");

// Changing li according custumOrder
for (var item of custumOrder) {
  ul.append($('#' + item + ''));
}

$("#sortable").sortable();

$("#get-index-button").on("click", function() {
  // Saving order of items
  var custumOrder = $("#sortable").sortable('toArray');
  alert(custumOrder.join(','));
});
```

[**Online demo (fiddleJs)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/ptk8a9r4/3/)